# How to embed PDF in a web page using Acrobat Reader instead of Acrobat

Tags: html, pdf, embed, acrobat

I have a pdf form that uses Acrobat 8 features. The form contains Javascript that interacts with the hosting web page.

Some of my Windows users have both Adobe Acrobat and Acrobat Reader installed, and need Adobe Acrobat to be the default handler for pdf files. The users with Adobe Acrobat 7 are unable to use the form, even though they might have Acrobat Reader 8 or 9 installed.

Currently, the PDF is embedded like this:

```
<object id="host" data="/path/to/document.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="900" height="550" ></object>
```

Answer (score 2):

The PDF is loaded in client browser and you can't control that from your web page.

You will need the client to make sure that their PDF is by default associated with the later version of the reader. Two possible things to do:

- In acrobat reader 8/9, go to Help and select repair this installation. It may then register this version correctly as the default PDF program to launch for PDF content
- In the browser, go to Tools->Options and choose Set Programs to associate the PDF types with Acrobat Reader 8/9.